# Why is EF in .NET randomly adding a column suffixed with 1?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have a `Group` model, which has a has-one relation for `GroupPermissionSet`, which in turn contains permissions.

The `Group` model

```
public class Group
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Description { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public int? PermissionSetId { get; set; }
    public GroupPermissionSet? PermissionSet { get; set; }
}
```

However, the resulting migrations from .NET EF migrations adds the following

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Groups",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("MySql:ValueGenerationStrategy", MySqlValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
                    Name = table.Column<string>(type: "longtext", nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("MySql:CharSet", "utf8mb4"),
                    Description = table.Column<string>(type: "longtext", nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("MySql:CharSet", "utf8mb4"),
                    PermissionSetId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: true),
                    PermissionSetId1 = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: true)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Groups", x => x.Id);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_Groups_GroupPermissionSets_PermissionSetId1",
                        column: x => x.PermissionSetId1,
                        principalTable: "GroupPermissionSets",
                        principalColumn: "Id");
                })
                .Annotation("MySql:CharSet", "utf8mb4");
```

Which contains a `PermissionSetId1` for some weird random reason. I think this is a bug, unless it's me who misunderstood how one-to-one relations are made in .NET.

I have tried removing the `PermissionSetId` from the model, this did not work either.

Comment: What version of .NET and EF are you using?

Comment: Try marking `PermissionSetId` with `[ForeignKey(nameof(PermissionSet))]`. Your code should work as is but for some reason the convention is not picked up.

Comment: @GuruStron it didnt work, im using dotnet 7 and ef 6

Comment: JIC EF 6 Core? Can you share a full [mre] somewhere?

Comment: Can you please update your question to include this GroupPermissionSet class? Your explanation has a few red flags where you at first indicate a Many-to-One relationship (Many groups belong to a GroupPermissionSet) but then mention a One-to-One relationship. The error can be occurring due to a convention issue on either end of the relationship so the problem may be in your GroupPermissionSet definition. Guru's comment about the ForeignKey attribute is bang on and would normally be needed since EF convention uses the Type name not the Property name by default.